# Loading picture from camera into ImageView

Tags: android, image, imageview, uri

In my app, I have it so that when the user clicks on the Camera button it takes him to the camera using an intent.

He then takes the picture and it should load it back into the ImageView I have on the same screen as the Camera button.

I think something is wrong with my screen orientation. When I load the camera view it switches to horizontal orientation, and when it closes it switches back to vertical orientation and my whole screen resets back to default.

This is the error I get in logcat:

```
12-03 20:14:38.440: E/SpannableStringBuilder(15134): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is what happens:

- I click on the camera button.
- the screen camera view switches to horizontal mode, but I am holding it vertically so it switches to vertical.
- I take the picture in horizontal mode.
- The camera app asks me to save my pic or cancel it in vertical mode.
- I click save.
- My app loads in horizontal mode and places the picture inside the imageView.
- The app then switches back to vertical mode and resets the whole screen.

I put your alls code in, but it isn't helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

All I did was add that line of code and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Also the point to be noted is that camera is by default in android works in landscape mode only. So no matter what you screen orientation is, the camera will launch in horizontal mode only. Also as above mentioned do

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

And handle this in your activity be using the below callback

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {       
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
```

}

Comment: I put the code in, but it still isn't working. read my edited post for a description of what happens.

Comment: What do you mean by reset the whole screen? Does the taken image goes away and image view shows nothing? I would suggest do all the onCreate operations in an init() method and call the same init in onConfigurationchanged.

Comment: After I take the picture. it is loaded into the imageview during horizontal mode. After one second of that it is set back back vertical and all of the images on the screen revert back to their original.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your activity gets reseted is because of the screen orientation change made by the camera intent.

You can put `android:configChanges="orientation"` inside your activity in the androidManifest.xml

Once you have that, it would not destroy and recreate your activity.

Please see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config for more details

Comment: I put the code in, but it still isn't working. read my edited post for a description of what happens